# Planar Graph - Proof

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

If graph G is a planar graph with less than 30 edges: $|E| \lt 30$, prove that the minimum degree in G is: $δ(G) \le 4$.

I was thinking to somehow combine:

- if graph is planar $\Rightarrow |E| \le 3* |V| - 6$
- $2 * |E| =$ sum of degrees in G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, if $\delta(G)\ge 5$, then 
$$ \tag12|E|=\sum_{v\in V}\rho(v)\ge \delta(G)|V|\ge 5|V|$$
combined with  $$\tag2 3|V|-6\ge |E|$$
gives us $3(1)+5(2)$:
$$6|E|+15|V|-30\ge 15|V|+5|E|$$
or after cancellation,$$|E|\ge 30. $$

Comment: I didn't know you could combine (1) and (2) like that. A neat trick! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Let's $\delta(G) = 5$, then $5|V| \le 2|E|$. Since $G$ is planar, $3|F| \le 2|E|$. So by Euler's formula we have
$$
2 = |V|-|E|+|F| \le \frac{|E|}{15},
$$ 
which implies $|E| \ge 30$.